# Give users a stripped down version of add node page and then require admin approval

Tags: 6, nodes, forms

I want to give my users stripped down versions of the 'add node' pages to create nodes of various content types. Once they fill out the stripped down version (less fields and options) an admin/editor can then approve each node manually and fill in fields not in the stripped form. What method or modules can I use to achieve this?

For example, a user would fill in the title, body, tags and the admin would fill in custom fields such as the imagefield, filefield etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign permissions to fields, the content permissions module should give you what you want. Look in the permissions pages and you can see what rolls have access to which fields.

A simple way to set up the workflow you suggested is to set the default node status to unpublished (look under workflow settings on the edit content type page). Then make sure only your admin role has the *administer nodes* permission.

Comment: I have some nodes created by the Feeds module that I want to be published by default. Is there a different way?